# how to search name like mysql does from json or array data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, pattern-matching

I want to search data from array in jquery but I am facing some issue.

When I pass **Wayfarer** value in `src_keyword` variable,it returns relative data

**ISSUE**

But issue is that when I pass  **Wayfarer Bag** value in `src_keyword` variable,it returns empty but it should return `Wayfarer Messenger Bag`.

Here is code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var src_keyword = 'Wayfarer Bag';
var array = [ "Foo", "Joust Duffle Bag", "Wayfarer Messenger Bag", "Voyage Yoga Bag", "pushit Messagenger bag" ]; //sample data

arr = $.map(array, function (value) {
                      var search = new RegExp(src_keyword, "gi");
                      if(value.match(search)) return value;

                      return null;
                    }
                 );
   console.log(arr);              
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess your only options to add a lazy dot star between two keywords words, e.g. [`Wayfarer.*?Bag`](https://regex101.com/r/8RgntD/1) or treat them as separate keywords, e.g. `Wayfarer|Bag`

Comment: @wp78de any solution for if I enter 'Bag Wayfarer' in reverse order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [wp78de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291949/wp78de) brilliantly mentionned in comment... You have to modify the string used as a regular expression.

Below, I used a for loop to insert the `.*?` characters between words.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var src_keyword = 'Wayfarer Bag';
  var array = [ "Foo", "Joust Duffle Bag", "Wayfarer Messenger Bag", "Voyage Yoga Bag", "pushit Messagenger bag" ]; //sample data

  var multipleSearchWords = src_keyword.split(" ");
  var regex="";
  var result=[];
  
  for(i=0;i<multipleSearchWords.length;i++){
    regex+=multipleSearchWords[i];
    if(i<multipleSearchWords.length-1){
      regex+=".*?";
    }
  }
  
  console.log(regex);
  
  result = $.map(array, function (value) {
    var search = new RegExp(regex, "gi");
    if(value.match(search)){
      return value;
    }
    return null;
  });
  
  console.log(result);              
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now those words have to be in the right order... ;)

Comment: thank you very much Louys Patrice Bessettle. You saved my time and thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: any solution for if I enter 'Bag Wayfarer' rather than 'Wayfarer Bag' ? its reverse order

Comment: mmm... You could code an additionnal block with an if statement to check if there is no result -> [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array and retry...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex test in a simple filter (I'm assuming you simply want to match all wayferer items)

```
var array = [ "Foo", "Joust Duffle Bag", "Wayfarer Messenger Bag", "Bag Wayfarer", "Bag Way farer Way Bag", "Voyage Yoga Bag", "pushit Messagenger bag" ]; // sample data

var arr = array.filter(function (value) { // Native Array.Filter is supported all the way down to IE9 so no need for jquery FYI
    return (/wayfarer/gi.test(value)); // Will return true for every entry that contains the text 'wayfarer' anywhere in the string
});

console.log(arr); // arr = (2) ["Wayfarer Messenger Bag", "Bag Wayfarer"]
```